# How to use the regular expression group In Lugaru Epsilon (Editor) when the total match exceeds 9 groups?

Tags: regex, epsilon

This is about regular expression replacement in the [Epsilon](http://www.lugaru.com/) editor. I have a `csv` file that I wanted to replace the texts with a certain pattern.

The pattern replacement works perfectly when I use **#1**,  **#2**  etc., in the replacement group.

But, when I enter **#10**, its the first group that got placed here. How to use the matching group greater than 9?

Comment: Try `#{10}`. If that does not work, it might be that the regex flavor is POSIX BRE that only supports 1 to 9 backreferences and you can't use a tenth backreference.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but its not working. How to locate that mentioned POSIX BRE in that editor?

Comment: No idea. BTW, you may try replacing `{}` with `<>` since this is used in Epsilon regex constructions.

Comment: This doesn't work either. BTW, `()` used in constructions, have tried that one also

Answer (score 0):

(Well, a very late answer, I realize now; anyway...)

I'm not able to find the documentation, but I think that only 1 (0 for the whole patter)  to 9 (at least in interactive command) are supported.

I found this code, in src/searc.e:

```
...
char *with;
...
if (*with != '#')
    insert(*with);
else if (isdigit(*++with)) {
    bufnum = orig;
    group = *with - '0';
    buf_xfer(tmp, find_group(group, 1),
        find_group(group, 0));
    bufnum = tmp;
} else {
...
```

It seems to me the only the first character after # is considered.

You may try to mail to support@lugaru.com for further clarification, I found Steven Doerfler always very helpfull (Epsilon 14 is now in beta, it could be an opportunity to improve the documentation.)